# Regex to Retrieve Quoted String and Quote Character

Tags: java, regex

I have a language that defines a string as being delimited by either single or double quotes, where the delimiter is escaped within the string by doubling it.  For example, all of the following are legal strings:

```
'This isn''t easy to parse.'
'Then John said, "Hello Tim!"'
"This isn't easy to parse."
"Then John said, ""Hello Tim!"""
```

I have a collection of strings (defined above), delimited by something that doesn't contain a quote.  What I am attempting to do using regular expressions, is to parse each string in a list out.  For example, here is an input:

> "Some String #1" OR 'Some String #2' AND "Some 'String' #3" XOR
>   'Some "String" #4' HOWDY "Some ""String"" #5" FOO 'Some ''String'' #6'

The regular expression to determine whether a string is of such a form is trivial:

```
^(?:"(?:[^"]|"")*"|'(?:[^']|'')*')(?:\s+[^"'\s]+\s+(?:"(?:[^"]|"")*"|'(?:[^']|'')*')*
```

After running the above expression to test whether it is of such a form, I need another regular expression to get each delimited string from the input.  I plan to do this as follows:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("What REGEX goes here?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
int startIndex = 0;
while (matcher.find(startIndex))
{
    String quote        = matcher.group(1);
    String quotedString = matcher.group(2);
    ...
    startIndex = matcher.end();
}
```

I would like a regular expression that captures the quote character in group #1, and the text within quotes in group #2 (I am using Java Regex).  So, for the above input, I am looking for a regular expression that produces the following output within each loop iteration:

```
Loop 1: matcher.group(1) = "
        matcher.group(2) = Some String #1
Loop 2: matcher.group(1) = '
        matcher.group(2) = Some String #2
Loop 3: matcher.group(1) = "
        matcher.group(2) = Some 'String' #3
Loop 4: matcher.group(1) = '
        matcher.group(2) = Some "String" #4
Loop 5: matcher.group(1) = "
        matcher.group(2) = Some ""String"" #5
Loop 6: matcher.group(1) = '
        matcher.group(2) = Some ''String'' #6
```

Patterns I have tried thus far (un-escaped, followed by escaped for Java code):

```
(["'])((?:[^\1]|\1\1)*)\1
"([\"'])((?:[^\\1]|\\1\\1)*)\\1"

(?<quot>")(?<val>(?:[^"]|"")*)"|(?<quot>')(?<val>(?:[^']|'')*)'
"(?<quot>\")(?<val>(?:[^\"]|\"\")*)\"|(?<quot>')(?<val>(?:[^']|'')*)'"
```

Both of these fail when trying to compile the pattern.

Is such a regular expression possible?

Comment: [See the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).  They don't mention supporting backslash references :(

Comment: About a quarter of the way down the page you linked there is a section titled "Back references", which includes the text "\n Whatever the nth capturing group matched".

Comment: What is the "text between quotes" that you want to capture in the second gorup? Is it `this isn''t easy to parse` (escaped) or `this isn't easy to parse` unescaped?

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary that you use regex to solve this problem or can you write some code to parse the string?

Comment: Just to clarify, which quote do you want to capture: The one that wraps the entire input (first and last char), or the one that wraps the inner quoted part?

Comment: @Bohemian Sorry, my question was written in such a way that it was unclear.  I have edited it to clarify the desired output.

Comment: @abl *every problem can be solved by throwing enough RegEx at it*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a utility class that matches for you:

```
class test {
    private static Pattern pd = Pattern.compile("(\")((?:[^\"]|\"\")*)\"");
    private static Pattern ps = Pattern.compile("(')((?:[^']|'')*)'");
    public static Matcher match(String s) {
        Matcher md = pd.matcher(s);
        if (md.matches()) return md;
        else return ps.matcher(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that will return whether a string matches a given pattern, but if double quoted, the result will be in group #1, whereas a single-quoted string would be in group #2.  Is there a way to get the quote character in group #1, and the quoted text in group #2, regardless of the quote type used?

Comment: Use a method that matches on the left regex, then the right.  If first matches return the first Matcher, else return the second Matcher

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much what I ended up doing.  I realized that I have no business rule stating that I need the matches in the requested groups, and ultimately I just need to convert strings delimited with double quotes into strings delimited with single quotes.  I ended up using the regex "('(?:[^']|'')*')|\"((?:[^\"]|\"\")*)\"".  If group #1 matches, I am done.  If group #2 matches, I do some extra work to un-escape double quotes and escape single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking for, but you can just write some code to parse the string and get the desired results (quote character and inner text) instead of using a regular expression.

```
class Parser {

  public static ParseResult parse(String str)
  throws ParseException {

    if(str == null || (str.length() < 2)){
      throw new ParseException();
    }

    Character delimiter = getDelimiter(str);

    // Remove delimiters
    str = str.substring(1, str.length() -1);

    // Unescape escaped quotes in inner string
    String escapedDelim = "" + delimiter + delimiter;
    str = str.replaceAll(escapedDelim, "" + delimiter);

    return new ParseResult(delimiter, str);
  }

  private static Character getDelimiter(String str)
  throws ParseException {
    Character firstChar = str.charAt(0);
    Character lastChar = str.charAt(str.length() -1);

    if(!firstChar.equals(lastChar)){
      throw new ParseException(String.format(
            "First char (%s) doesn't match last char (%s) for string %s",
           firstChar, lastChar, str
      ));
    }

    return firstChar;
  }

}
```

```
class ParseResult {

  public final Character delimiter;
  public final String contents;

  public ParseResult(Character delimiter, String contents){
    this.delimiter = delimiter;
    this.contents = contents;
  }

}
```

```
class ParseException extends Exception {

  public ParseException(){
    super();
  }

  public ParseException(String msg){
    super(msg);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
"^('|\")(.*)\\1$"
```

Some test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] tests = {
            "'This isn''t easy to parse.'",
            "'Then John said, \"Hello Tim!\"'",
            "\"This isn't easy to parse.\"",
            "\"Then John said, \"\"Hello Tim!\"\"\""};
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^('|\")(.*)\\1$");
    Arrays.stream(tests).map(pattern::matcher).filter(Matcher::find).forEach(m -> System.out.println("1=" + m.group(1) + ", 2=" + m.group(2)));
}
```

Output:

```
1=', 2=This isn''t easy to parse.
1=', 2=Then John said, "Hello Tim!"
1=", 2=This isn't easy to parse.
1=", 2=Then John said, ""Hello Tim!""
```

---

If you're interested on how to capturing the quoted text within text:

This regex matches all variants and captures the quote in group 1 and the quoted text in group 6:

```
^((')|("))(.*?("\3|")(.*)\5)?.*\1$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/kXuNGXuYOK).

---

Here's some test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] tests = {
            "'This isn''t easy to parse.'",
            "'Then John said, \"Hello Tim!\"'",
            "\"This isn't easy to parse.\"",
            "\"Then John said, \"\"Hello Tim!\"\"\""};
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^((')|(\"))(.*?(\"\\3|\")(.*)\\5)?.*\\1$");
    Arrays.stream(tests).map(pattern::matcher).filter(Matcher::find)
      .forEach(m -> System.out.println("quote=" + m.group(1) + ", quoted=" + m.group(6)));
}
```

Output:

```
quote=', quoted=null
quote=', quoted=Hello Tim!
quote=", quoted=null
quote=", quoted=Hello Tim!
```

Comment: I realize that my question was unclear, and have tried to remove the ambiguity that lead you to this answer.

Comment: @Jeff Easy. See new answer.

Comment: Ok, my test cases clearly don't cover what I am trying to do, which is parse quote-delimited strings out of a comma-delimited list.  I'll add another test to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions for this type of problem is very challenging.  A simple parser that does not use regex is much easier to implement, understand, and maintain.

In addition, such a simple parse can easily support things like backslash escapes, and conversion of backslash sequences to characters (e.g. "\n" conversion to a newline character).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very easily with a simple regex like below

```
private static Object[] checkPattern(String name, String regex) {
    List<String> matchedString = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        if (matcher.group().length() > 0) {
            matchedString.add(matcher.group());
        }
    }
    return matchedString.toArray();
}


@Test
public void quotedtextMultipleQuotedLines() {
    String text = "He said, \"I am Tom\". She said, \"I am Lisa\".";
    String quoteRegex = "(\"[^\"]+\")";
    String[] strArray = {"\"I am Tom\"", "\"I am Lisa\""};
    assertArrayEquals(strArray, checkPattern(text, quoteRegex));
}
```

We get the strings as the array elements here.